# Window.h c++ how to get index of a button from an array inside switch

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I have one question for you. I just started to learn C++ GUI (windows.h) and I got a problem. I have to do for my mother a program that record some information so I designed a GuI that add a new set of empty field every time I click on "Adaugare" button . Near every set of fields, on right, there is a button named "Scrie" that should get the information from textBoxes and store it into a string. The problem is when I press the button to get the info, I don t know how to make my switch to figure out what field I want to get . Example : I writed 5 records, but I want to modify the first one, so how do I get the index of it even thought I have another 5 set of fields after ?
PLEASE HELP ME GUYS !

```
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
#define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
HWND button[5];
HWND banda[100];
HWND tip[100];
HWND lungime[100];
HWND latime[100];
HWND data[100];
HWND button_valideaza[100];

int i = 1;
char textSaved[20];



/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
TCHAR szClassName[ ] = _T("CodeBlocksWindowsApp");

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPSTR lpszArgument,
                 int nCmdShow)
{

MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

/* The Window structure */
wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

/* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
/* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

/* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
    return 0;

/* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
       0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
       szClassName,         /* Classname */
       _T("Flux Artego"),       /* Title Text */
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
       700,                 /* The programs width */
       300,                 /* and height in pixels */
       HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
       NULL,                /* No menu */
       hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
       NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
       );

/* Make the window visible on the screen */
ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);

/* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
    TranslateMessage(&messages);
    /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
    DispatchMessage(&messages);
}

/* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

void scrie() {
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
{
    case WM_CREATE:   // fac butoane, label etc

            button[0] =  CreateWindow("BUTTON",
                                   "Iesire",
                                   WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                                   560, 220, 100, 20,
                                   hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);   // (HMENU) 1 reprezinta care case din switch se executa
            button[1] =  CreateWindow("BUTTON",
                   "Adauga",
                   WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                   450, 220, 100, 20,
                   hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);


        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:  // fac instructiuni butoane

        switch(LOWORD(wParam) )
        {
            case 1:
                //::MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
                //::MessageBox(hwnd, "Ai salvat ?", "atentie", MB_OKCANCEL);
                cout << "GoodBye!";
                PostQuitMessage (0);
            break;

            case 2:   // Adaug nou record

                banda[i] = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                                          "EP",
                                          WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                          20, 30 * i, 30, 25,
                                          hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                tip[i] = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                                          "100",
                                          WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                          55, 30 * i, 100, 25,
                                          hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                lungime[i] = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                                          "Lungime",
                                          WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                          160, 30 * i, 100, 25,
                                          hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                latime[i] = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                                          "Latime",
                                          WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                          265, 30 * i, 100, 25,
                                          hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

                data[i] = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                                          "Data",
                                          WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                          370, 30 * i, 100, 25,
                                          hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                button_valideaza[i] =  CreateWindow("BUTTON",
                                           "Scrie",
                                           WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                                           475, 30 * i, 80, 20,
                                           hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                i++;
            break;

            case 3:   // scriu record



               int gwtstat = 0;
               gwtstat = GetWindowText(banda[i], &textSaved[0], 20);


            break;
        }

        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
        break;
    default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CreateWindow` should normally be called in response to `WM_CREATE`. Your question is not clear, and it's not clear what your program is supposed to do.  WinAPI programming is not trivial, you have to pick up a book. If you can't invest the time to study this then consider other tools like managed languages etc.

Comment: Maybe put each pair of form-button in some kind of group. I'm not familiar with WinAPI, but probbaly you are able to find the group where the button is in and then find the form in that group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the different command for each "Scrie" Button , set its Menu like that:

```
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
#define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
HWND button[5];
HWND banda[100];
HWND tip[100];
HWND lungime[100];
HWND latime[100];
HWND data1[100];
HWND button_valideaza[100];

int i = 0;
char textSaved[20];



/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
TCHAR szClassName[] = _T("CodeBlocksWindowsApp");

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpszArgument,
    int nCmdShow)
{

    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

                             /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
                                               /* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
        szClassName,         /* Classname */
        _T("Flux Artego"),       /* Title Text */
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
        CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
        CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
        700,                 /* The programs width */
        300,                 /* and height in pixels */
        HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
        NULL,                /* No menu */
        hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
        NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
    );

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

void scrie() {
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    WORD cmd = LOWORD(wParam);
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
    case WM_CREATE:   // fac butoane, label etc

        button[0] = CreateWindow("BUTTON",
            "Iesire",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            560, 220, 100, 20,
            hwnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);   // (HMENU) 1 reprezinta care case din switch se executa
        button[1] = CreateWindow("BUTTON",
            "Adauga",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
            450, 220, 100, 20,
            hwnd, (HMENU)2, NULL, NULL);


        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:  // fac instructiuni butoane
        switch (cmd)
        {
        case 1:
            //::MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
            //::MessageBox(hwnd, "Ai salvat ?", "atentie", MB_OKCANCEL);
            cout << "GoodBye!";
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case 2:   // Adaug nou record

            banda[i] = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                "EP",
                WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                20, 30 * i, 30, 25,
                hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            tip[i] = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                "100",
                WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                55, 30 * i, 100, 25,
                hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            lungime[i] = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                "Lungime",
                WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                160, 30 * i, 100, 25,
                hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            latime[i] = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                "Latime",
                WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                265, 30 * i, 100, 25,
                hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            data1[i] = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                "Data",
                WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                370, 30 * i, 100, 25,
                hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            button_valideaza[i] = CreateWindow("BUTTON",
                "Scrie",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                475, 30 * i, 80, 20,
                hwnd, (HMENU)(i+3), NULL, NULL);
            i++;
            break;

        default:
            if (cmd > 2 && cmd < 103)
            {
                int gwtstat = 0;
                gwtstat = GetWindowText(banda[cmd-3], &textSaved[0], 20);
                ::MessageBox(hwnd, textSaved,"text", MB_OKCANCEL);
            }
            break;
        }

        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
        break;
    default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```